# How do different methods to determine IP-address ranges work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, range, ip-address, access-control

I want do deny the access to my Website for IP-Adresses from a certain IP range. (e.g. 143.56.122.127-143.56.122.255). I have found 4 different methods to do this on a Apache-Server:

- Use a `Deny from ###.###.###.###` for each IP-address. This can be lots of work,...
- `Deny from ###.###.###.###/XX`. I could not find out how I have to determine the number XX so that it does what I want.
- `Deny from ###.###.###.###/255.255.255.126`. This is what I think could work for my specific example. I think it means that the difference to 255 of each part of the second IP-address is added to the first IP-address.
- The fourth is one with pattern-matching, but this was not very intuitive and thus probably not the easiest way for most cases.

I think the second and third seem to be most straight forward, so can anybody explain them to me. do these methods have a name or are use in a standard?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can use second method.

```
Order allow,deny
//0.0.0.0 - 0.255.255.255.255
Allow from 0.0.0.0/8

//1.0.0.0 - 1.1.255.255
Allow from 1.0.0.0/15

//1.2.0.0 - 1.2.1.255
Allow from 1.2.0.0/23

//1.2.2.0 - 1.2.2.255
Allow from 1.2.2.0/24

//1.2.3.0 - 1.2.3.3
Allow from 1.2.3.0/30
```

This way, you can write

```
//143.56.122.127-143.56.122.255
Deny from 143.56.122.0/24
Allow from 143.56.122.0/25
```

You can also refer [this](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/). Though, i would like to make it pristine that i have never used in my project yet. This is suggestion. I would also like to read from others on this.

Comment: +1 But, according to [whois](http://www.whois.net/ip-address-lookup/143.56.122.127) the NetRange for that address is `143.56.0.0 to 143.56.255.255` and the CIDR is `143.56.0.0/16`, so I guess the OP should ban that whole range, instead of part of it only.

Comment: This was an IP that I made up as an example. +1 for the whois-link.